# How to turn items in an array into bytes for hashing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, hashlib

I am trying to hash a user input which is entered through easygui. Easygui stores the input into an array (I think), so when I try to hash the userinput I am not sure how to turn it into a byte.

Here is my code:

```
import hashlib
import easygui


g = hashlib.sha256(b'helloworld').hexdigest()

l = easygui.enterbox('enter password')

f = hashlib.sha256([l]).hexdigest()

print(g)
print(f)
```

ideally if I type 'helloworld' into the easygui, it should return the same hashed output.

The error currently is:

```
"TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required" at the line f = haslib.sha256([l]).hexdigest()
```

Comment: Why do you wrap `l` with list(`[l]`)? I don't know about `easygui` but you can try `hashlib.sha256(l)` instead of `hashlib.sha256([l])`.

Comment: You can try `hashlib.sha256('helloworld'.encode())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`easygui.enterbox` returns the text that the user entered, or None if he cancels the operation. You will have to convert the text returned to byte array. [Docs](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/api.html)

```
if l is not None:
    f = hashlib.sha256(l.encode()).hexdigest()
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution works. I will read into the documentation as well to understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

You have to encode your given string bevor you can hash it. The easiest way would, to just use the for strings implemented encode() method.

`f = hashlib.sha256(l.encode()).hexdigest()
print(f)`

with return your sha256 hash.